# Does there exist an explicit expression for the series ( or function) $f(x)=\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty e^{-xn^2}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Does there exist an explicit expression for the series (or function) $$f(x)=\sum _{n=1}^\infty e^{-xn^2}\text{ ?}$$

Comment: Search "theta function".

Comment: i mean something that doesn't involve theta function, a function like the limit of the goemetric series

Comment: $\theta_{{3}} \left(0,q \right) =1+2\,\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{q}^{{n}^{2
}}$ and that is the simplest known way to write it.

Comment: ...and what's your objection against the theta function?

Comment: ok, but i'd like to know if there exists a function(x) which is the limit of that series, such as the integral of $exp(-x^2)$ can't be express with elementary function

Comment: Yes, the theta function is not elementary. Yes, it's the limit of your series. @GEdgar already gave you the precise expression. Now, what else?

Comment: i'd like to know if exists a simpler expression, and if it is possible to find out

Comment: Did you read GEdgar's comment carefully? $\frac12(\vartheta_3(0,\exp(-x))-1)$ is as simple as it gets.

Comment: mmmmmm now i ask an epression without theta function or a proof of the fact that the theta function is the only way for rappresenting it

Comment: if i would calculate a particular x of this function, how could i do it if the theta function expresses an identity?

Answer (score 2):

There is some more information about your sum that can be obtained using Mellin transforms.
We have $$\mathfrak{M}(f(x); s) = f^*(s) = \Gamma(s) \zeta(2s).$$

Now invert by calculating the sum of the residues of $f^*(s) x^{-s}$. They are
$$ \operatorname{Res}(f^*(s) x^{-s}; s= 1/2) = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
\quad \text{and} \quad
 \operatorname{Res}(f^*(s) x^{-s}; s= 0) = - \frac{1}{2}.$$
The remaining poles of the gamma function are canceled by the zeros of the zeta function, giving $$f(x) \sim \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} - \frac{1}{2}.$$
This asymptotic expansion holds in a neighborhood of zero.

Comment: thanks :) I just want to know why we use an elliptic function to express this function and not a "simpler" function. Which properties has it got?